# C++ Run-time Managed Object Type Not Known Prior to Compile Time?

Tags: c++, native, intellisense, unmanaged, managed

I'm trying to develop a Native to/from Managed project in Visual Studio 2012 with C++ and C#. However, I'm running into the following issue:

I have an Object defined in my C# dll called `Shape` coded as so:

**ShapeFactory.cs**

```
public class Shape
{
   private Circle[] collection;
   public Circle[] Collection { get { return this.collection; } set { this.collection = value; } }

   private string color;
   public string Color { get { return this.color; } set { this.color = value; } }
}

public class Circle
{
   private Attributes[] attr;
   public Attributes[] Attr { get { return this.attr; } set { this.attr = value; } }

   private int radius;
   public int Radius { get { return this.radius; } set { this.radius= value; } }
}

public class Attributes
{
   private int height;
   public int Height{ get { return this.height; } set { this.height = value; } }

   private int width;
   public int Width{ get { return this.width; } set { this.width = value; } }
}
```

**ShapeFactoryCPP.cpp**

```
#using "ShapeFactory.dll"
#include <msclr\gcroot.h>
#include "ShapeFactoryCPP.h"

void GetShape(ShapeManaged ^ managed)
{
    ShapeManaged % managedRef = *managed;

    int collectionCount = managedRef.Collection->Length;

    if(collectionCount > 0)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < collectionCount ; i++)
        {
            if(managedRef.Collection[i] != nullptr)
            {
                auto x = managedRef.Collection[i]->radius;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is compiled to a `ShapeFactory.dll` and included as a `#using ShapeFactory.dll` in my C++. I create pass a Managed object to a C# function and set the managed object from C++ to a Json.Net serialized object as shown above. However, I cannot seem to find the collection's fields in C++ when attempting to get call `managedRef.Collection[0]->attr` or `managedRef.Collection[0]->radius`. Visual Studio's IntelliSense throws the following syntax error but still compiles and works:

```
Error: class System:Object has no member "radius"
```

And when I debug this and add `managedRef->Collection[i]->radius` as a watch variable it shows the correct value and `managedRef->Collection[i]` shows the collection and type Circle. How can I make IntelliSense aware of the collection's type? Am I missing a configuration setting somewhere for IntelliSense or defining my C# objects without providing the necessary information for C++ to pick up the object types?

Comment: It is not very obvious what ShapeManaged might be and why its Collection member element type is Object instead of Shape.  But the rule is the same in C++ as it is in C#, you have to cast to get a valid reference to a Circle.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1bh3t52k.aspx

Comment: So I would need to upcast in C# so that C++ knows the object type?
I tried adding 'public class Shape : Circle' and 'public class Circle : Attributes' in place of the class signatures in ShapeFactory.cs but it doesn't seem to work? Am I misunderstanding the casting bit?